# ASP .NET CompareValidator control locks everything

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a form with a field that has a `asp:CompareValidator` control which checks if the text in the input is of type `Integer`.

The problem is that the form has some other buttons to navigate to other pages, so when the CompareValidator triggers it locks those buttons until the input in the controled field is Integer although it's not necessary to navigate.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRelacion" placeholder="Id del evento"></asp:TextBox>                                                                                                                 
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="txtRelacion" CssClass="compare-validation-error" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitButton" Text="Submit Form"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="navigateButton" Text="Navigate somewhere"/>
```

Is this the expected behaviour of the `asp:CompareValidator` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `ValidationGroup` in your button and in your CompareValidator. Then the CompareValidator will be used only for the corresponding ValidationGroup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRelacion" placeholder="Id del evento"></asp:TextBox>                                                                                                                 
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="txtRelacion" ValidationGroup="form" CssClass="compare-validation-error" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitButton" ValidationGroup="form" Text="Submit Form"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="navigateButton" Text="Navigate somewhere"/>
```

Comment: Faster than the "accept answer time".. Works like a charm!

Comment: Good! I'll have to wait then ;)